# Join objects seamlessly in Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode

Is it possible to join two objects in Blender without having the join seam showing? Thank you

Comment: Could you please elaborate, maybe with a picture and a few more words to make the situation more clear. Joining two objects in mesh mode or just visually by getting their vertices/geometry close enough together to appear seamless?

Comment: Yes, you have to join them in object mode then go into edit mode and create a cut in each mesh where you would like them to be connected seamlessly. Keeping clean topology in mind and then connect them. You can then separate them once more based off of the selection. Selection one object that was connected and then right click and separate by selection.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: The question is pretty straight forward. I am sure that I answered it.

Comment: I posted a picture with the two meshes that i would like to join them seamlessly. The topology is pretty heavy on both and with different directions. I would like you to take a look at the picture and tell me if what you said could be applied there.

Comment: @Daniel I can sadly not see any posted picture in this question of yours. I even went in the edit queque to see if something got lost, but that seems to be not the case. Please check again, so we can see and try to solve the problem.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan While you gave an answer in a way, it was a comment you put it in, write it in an answer if you are sure it is one for this question.

Comment: I cannot do that. The answer text box is not available because the forum moderator took it away because somebody flagged the question.

Comment: The comment was closed by Ramos and my second question with the picture completely erased. Not sure why that happened. Strange stuff.